# VB.NET oledbDataAdapter fill work only once

Tags: vb.net, adodb, recordset

So I have a recordset and I want to fill two datatable with it but it only fill the first datatable.

```
Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim dt1 As New DataTable
Dim rs1 As New ADODB.Recordset
rs1.Open("select * from table",conn,ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly)
da.Fill(dt1, rs1)

rs1.MoveFirst()

da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim dt2 As New DataTable
da.Fill(dt2, rs1)
```

So the first datatable (dt1) has data in it but dt2 is empty and I'm not sure why. I tried the MoveFirst() but it change nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using VB.Net, instead of VBA or VBScript, you **SHOULD NOT** use the old ADODB types like `RecordSet`. They exist for backwards compatibility only when porting forward old code, and *should not be used for new development.* You definitely shouldn't mix and match between the old adodb and new ADO.Net in the same place. Stick with ADO.Net.

In this case, we can replace old `RecordSet` with also-20yrs-old-now-but-not-as-old-as-adodb `OleDbCommand`:

```
Dim dt1 As New DataTable()
Dim dt2 As New DataTable()
Using conn As New OleDb.OleConnection("connection string here"), _
      cmd  As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("select * from table", conn), _
      da   As New OleDb.OleDbAdataAdapter(cmd)

    ' When using .Fill() you don't even need to call .Open()
    da.Fill(dt1)

    ' Optional
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from othertable"

    da.Fill(dt2)

End Using
```